# Itertools for containers

Tags: iterator, python

Considder the following interactive example

```
>>> l=imap(str,xrange(1,4))
>>> list(l)
['1', '2', '3']
>>> list(l)
[]
```

Does anyone know if there is already an implementation somewhere out there with a version of imap (and the other itertools functions) such that the second time list(l) is executed you get the same as the first. And I don't want the regular map because building the entire output in memory can be a waste of memory if you use larger ranges.

I want something that basically does something like

```
class cmap:
    def __init__(self, function, *iterators):
        self._function = function
        self._iterators = iterators

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.imap(self._function, *self._iterators)

    def __len__(self):
        return min( map(len, self._iterators) )
```

But it would be a waste of time to do this manually for all itertools if someone already did this.

ps.
Do you think containers are more zen then iterators since for an iterator something like

```
for i in iterator:
    do something
```

implicitly empties the iterator while a container you explicitly need to remove elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to build such an object for each type of container. Basically, you have the following:

```
mkimap = lambda: imap(str,xrange(1,4))
list(mkimap())
list(mkimap())
```

Now you onlky need a nice wrapping object to prevent the "ugly" function calls. This could work this way:

```
class MultiIter(object):
    def __init__(self, f, *a, **k):
        if a or k:
            self.create = lambda: f(*a, **k)
        else: # optimize
            self.create = f
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.create()

l = MultiIter(lambda: imap(str, xrange(1,4)))
# or
l = MultiIter(imap, str, xrange(1,4))
# or even
@MultiIter
def l():
    return imap(str, xrange(1,4))

# and then
print list(l)
print list(l)
```

(untested, hope it works, but you should get the idea)

For your 2nd question: Iterators and containers both have their uses. You should take whatever best fits your needs.

Comment: I choose this answer since I like the lambda construct if you just want to get this result without writing your own function or class.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [itertools.tee()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

Comment: This won't work for the OP. From the docs: “This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage”, from the OP: “And I don't want the regular map because building the entire output in memory can be a waste of memory if you use larger ranges.”

Comment: Fair enough, but considering that not all iterators refer to a source that can actually be the same thing twice in a row, he'll either have to use memory to save them or restructure his program so as not to need the iterator twice.

Comment: Maybe parallelizing would be a good thing as well. My solution in the other answer has the drawback that the operation to get the next item must be quite cheap. If not, it might be helpful to use `tee()` and do the further evaluations parallel instead of sequential in order not to waste memory.

Comment: I often write data processing scripts using generators; for debugging, you can put `x = list(x)` in between steps, and for production, you leave them be.  That way it's basically in parallel when you need it.  The first step to optimization is always to make sure you are using the best algorithm (or paradigm).

Answer (score -1):

Iterators are my favorite topic ;)

```
from itertools import imap

class imap2(object):
    def __init__(self, f, *args):
        self.g = imap(f,*args)
        self.lst = []
        self.done = False

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            try: # try to get something from g
                x = next(self.g)
            except StopIteration:
                if self.done:
                    # give the old values
                    for x in self.lst:
                        yield x
                else:
                    # g was consumed for the first time
                    self.done = True
                return
            else:
                self.lst.append(x)
                yield x




l=imap2(str,xrange(1,4))
print list(l)
print list(l)
```

Comment: This won't work for the OP: “And I don't want the regular map because building the entire output in memory can be a waste of memory if you use larger ranges.”